# What are good resources for discussing solutions to "Introduction to Statistical Learning in R"?

Tags: references, statistical-learning

This question is more about learning statistics than about statistics *per se*, so please suggest another forum if this one is not appropriate.

I found this textbook (ISLR by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani) online and it seems like a great resource.  I read a few chapters and then realized that I wasn't getting good comprehension.  So now I've decided to answer the questions at the end of each chapter and write them up in LaTeX/knitr.  I'm through chapter 3.

It would be amazing to discuss the solutions with other people who are using the same book.  Maybe I'm getting them all wrong!  Can anyone suggest a resource/forum/website where such a discussion might take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford online course, which is archived [here.](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/Winter2014/about)

Comment: That does not seem to be a permanent solution.

Comment: maybe not permanent, but pretty awesome!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few resources online for solutions:

A Solution Manual and Notes for ISLR by some MIT grad students (Weatherwax and Epstien) the posted a PDF easily found online (I would add PDF link but StackExchange won't let me add more than 2 links currently)

https://github.com/asadoughi/stat-learning/

http://srividya-rajesh.com/statlearning/

The 2<sup>nd</sup> link is someone's website. You could post questions on there and try to start a conversation. However a better solution would be PhysicsForums' website. I have had success posting data sci related problems there. They do a bunch of QA with homework type help and they usually have great and detailed discussions. They have a huge math/stats section with many experts willing to help.